# What resources do subtransaction IDs consume?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, upsert

[The PostgreSQL wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT#PostgreSQL_.28today.29) advises an approach to implementing UPSERT that uses a retry-loop. Implicit in this solution is the use of "subtransaction IDs". On the wiki article there is the following warning:

> The correct solution is slow and clumsy to use, and is unsuitable for significant amounts of data. It also potentially burns through a lot of subtransaction IDs - avoiding burning XIDs is an explicit goal of the current "native UPSERT in PostgreSQL" effort.

What is the consequence of using "a lot of subtransaction IDs"? I don't really know what a subtransaction ID is - is this just a way of numbering nested transactions, and is the implication that these numbers might run out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource is the 32 bits `XID` transaction counter itself, which is used by the engine to know if the version of a row in a table is associated to an "old" transaction (committed or rolled back) or a not-yet-committed transaction, and if it's visible or not from any given transaction.

Increasing XIDs at a super-high rate creates or increases the risk of getting a **transaction ID wraparound** issue. The worst case being that this issue escalates into a database self-shutdown to avoid data inconsistencies.

What avoids the transaction ID wraparound is routine vacuuming. This is  detailed in the doc under [Preventing Transaction ID Wraparound Failures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-WRAPAROUND).

But `autovacuum` is a background task which is meant to not get in the way of the foreground activity. Among other things, it cancels itself instead of locking out other queries. At times, it can lag a lot behind.

We can imagine a worst case where the foreground database activity increases  XID values so fast that autovacuum just doesn't have the time to freeze the rows with the "old XIDs" before these XIDs values are claimed by a new transaction or subtransaction, a situation which PostgreSQL couldn't deal with.

It might also be that those foreground transactions stay uncommitted when this is going on, so even an aggressive vaccum couldn't do anything about it.

That's why programmers should be cautious about techniques that make this event more likely, like opening/closing subtransactions in huge loops.

The range is about 2 billion transactions, but this is the kind of limit that was unreachable when the system was designed, but which will become problematic as our hardware capabilities and what we're asking from our databases are ever-increasing.